# show price info for hline in pine script

Tags: pine-script

How can I show price info to my hline object?

if I use draw tool of "horizontal line", I have rice info on right Y axis like the blue line. If I use hline to draw a line, I don't see the price label like the yellow line.

[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOgC5.png)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can use the plot function and "Indicator last value Label" setting.

```
plot(k, "plot the line", color.yellow, 2, plot.style_line, true, show_last=1)
```

Where k is the desired price that you want to plot a line at.

Could be used to plot the desired line and to show the price label you need to right click on scale and select settings. From the settings menu you need to select the  "Indicator last value Label" option.

[image]